# Kendo ASP.NET Core CheckBox Name prefix

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, asp.net-core

Suppose we have these two models

```
public class Item
{
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public bool BoolProperty { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And if we write this view `Test.cshtml`:

```
@model Item
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Detail, "TestTemplate")
```

And this template `TestTemplate.cshtml`:

```
@model Detail
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.BoolProperty)
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.StringProperty)
```

It will produce this html code:

```
<input class="k-checkbox" id="Detail_BoolProperty" name="BoolProperty" type="checkbox" value="true" /><label  *removed for brevity* </label><input name="BoolProperty" type="hidden" value="false" />
<input class="k-textbox" id="Detail_StringProperty" name="Detail.StringProperty" value="" />
```

Notice the names of checkbox input tag is `BoolProperty` not `Detail.BoolProperty` When the name of the textbox is `Detail.StringProperty`. Which will cause model binding problems.

Note that `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BoolProperty)` works properly.
I can think of two solutions:

1. Use await `TryUpdateModelAsync()` in the action with an empty string for the prefix parameter. I would like to avoid this solution as much as possible.
2. Use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BoolProperty, new { @class = "k-checkbox" })` But for some reason, the checkbox won't render at all!

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting, I found out that in order for the checkbox to be rendered, you'll have to also have a label with a `k-checkbox-label` class.

So this seems to work properly (`TestTemplate.cshtml`):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BoolProperty, new { @class = "k-checkbox" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BoolProperty, new { @class = "k-checkbox-label" })
```